# How to read an Excel sheet using Python considering row index and column name?

Tags: python, import-from-excel

I'm looking to read with Python an Excel workbook with 16 fields and about 100 rows. While reading I want to use the row index and for the column the name. The idea is that I get the columns in the file in a different order each time so the column index doesn't help much.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Seem to be some promising links to get you rolling with a quick google search and then Stack Overflow can help you work out the tweaks.

Comment: Most of the answer seem to lead to sheet.cell_value(row_index, col_index),  however instead of col_index it will be also useful to have the column_name as a possible argument somehow.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such think like column_name in Excel. The column name is just another cell that is depending on your sheet in the first row or in one of the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlrd or pyopenxl to read the content of the Excel workbook and put the content into a list of list: e.g.:

```
table = [["Name", "Age", "Ranking"], ["Sofia", 22, 10], ["Bill", 25, 10]]
```

You could parse the records and convert in instances for examples

```
class Record:
    pass

def convertToRecords(table):
    names = table[0]
    names = [name.lower() for name in names]
    names = [name.replace(" ", "_") for name in names]
    ret = []

    for row in table[1:]:
        record = Record()
        ret.append(record)
        for i, value in enumerate(row):
            setattr(record, names[i], row[i])

    return ret
```

You'll use that code like:

```
records = convertToRecords(table)
print records[0].name, records[0].age
```